# Alpine Linux: Convert Podman systemd to openrc

Tags: systemd, alpine-linux, podman, openrc

I use Alpine Linux and podman command to generate container systemd

**Command:**

```
podman generate systemd -n test -f
```

**Output:**

```
# container-test
# autogenerated by Podman 3.4.7
# Fri Apr 29 02:29:47 CEST 2022

[Unit]
Description=Podman container-test.service
Documentation=man:podman-generate-systemd(1)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
RequiresMountsFor=/run/containers/storage

[Service]
Environment=PODMAN_SYSTEMD_UNIT=%n
Restart=on-failure
TimeoutStopSec=70
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman start test
ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman stop -t 10 test
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/podman stop -t 10 test
PIDFile=/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/fc64dadf99ddb38f98ddcb3e022bc575ca39cd57f4e2e8c5cc63595377e2c3ad/userdata/conmon.pid
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Because Alpine Linux is not using systemd I need to convert this container service to openrc

**The Goal is:** 
to start specific containers as as service and this containers must be visible to root only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this converter
http://openrc.run/

This is more than enough to do conversion

Comment: I think it would be useful to future visitors if you included the output from that conversion in your answer -- or at least show how you installed, configured, and ran the link software in order to get your answer. Thank you!